# ALT+Tab no longer switches applications since upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

I have always used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key combo to switch between programs. Since upgrade to 18.04 only <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works.

How do I make both <kbd>Alt</kbd> buttons work with <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch applications?

Comment: this happen to me after upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04

Comment: worth noting here that , for me and 19.04 at least, I discovered that alt tab switches windows, and super tab switches applications. an application can have multiple windows, like Firefox and it's download window. I find that super tab preferable in that there are less icons to switch between, and I often have those multiple windows in another monitor anyway

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In the **Settings > Devices > Keyboard** menu, you will find a list of keyboard shortcuts. Under the **Navigation** section, you can find the relevant functions and their associated shortcuts, and change them as you see fit. You're looking for the one named *Switch applications*.

Comment: This does not work for me, neither alt tab nor the predefined super tab do anything

Comment: after some googeling I found a solution https://people.gnome.org/~federico/blog/alt-tab.html

Comment: check for `Switch windows directly` and double click it and **Alt** + **Tab** then clcik `set`. All done.

Answer (score 28):

Run `gnome-control-center` aka the **Settings** application.

Remove the shortcut for **Switch applications** by clicking on it and deleting it with the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key, now press the *Set* button.

Now set **Switch windows** by clicking on it, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and click the *Set* button.

Comment: how is this different from the other answers?

Comment: It's different because "Switch applications" is not the same as "Switch windows", setting "Switch applications" did not work with my setup.

Comment: This is the simplest and best.

Comment: @select thanks for pointing that part out, `switch windows` was definitely what I was expecting and not `switch applications`. Why that was changed in 18.04 I'll never understand because `alt+tab` to me (and probably most people) will mean "go back to the previous window". Just like you wouldn't change `ctrl+z` to act like `ctrl+backspace` - its not that same at all!

Answer (score 7):

Turns out the configuration just needs to be updated in settings.

Open **Settings > Devices > Keyboard** and under **Keyboard Shortcuts** select *Switch applications* and update it with left <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combinations should now work.

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to use `Alt + Esc`

Somehow maintainers think that this is better. However I always enable `Alt + Tab`

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding of the problem stated here is correct try the following solution. It is a three stage process
*Stage-1*:
(1) **Open Settings > Devices > Keyboard and under Keyboard Shortcuts**
(2) Remove the shortcut for **Switch applications** by clicking on it and deleting it with the **Backspace Key**, now press the **Set** button.
(3) Remove the shortcut for **Switch windos directly** by clicking on it and deleting it with the **Backspace Key**, now press the **Set** button.
*Stage-2*:
(1) Create a new shortcut for **Switch applications** by clicking on it and then press **Alt + Esc**  and click the **Set** button.
(2) Create a new shortcut for **Switch windos directly** by clicking on it and then press **Super + Tab**  and click the **Set** button.
What we have achieved so far is simply swapping the key combinations for the following actions
**Switch applications** and **Switch windos directly**
Now let us proceed to the next stage 
*Stage-3*:
(1) Create a new shortcut for **Switch windos** by clicking on it and then press **Alt + Tab**  and click the **Set** button.
Voila
You have restored the behavior of ALT + TAB Key to what is required in this post.
If for any reason things are not working you can execute the steps in *Stage-0* (mentioned below) and then redo steps in *Stage-1* and *Stage-2*
*Stage-0*:
(1) **Open Settings > Devices > Keyboard**
(2) In the top of the screen you can see the **Reset All...** button and then click it
(3) It will ask for confirmation. Click **Reset All**
**Caution**: TL;DR
The steps in this stage will remove any key customization you might have done in the past before you following the steps in this thread
That's all folks
Have a great time playing with keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu! Thanks for your contribution, however, I am not too sure how your answer really differs from any of the others, other than being more in depth. If you want to expand on an answer, it is better to just edit an existing answer with the extra info :)

Answer (score 1):

**To get the same settings in 18.04 where alt+tab switched apps and alt+` switched windows within the same app:**

Under `Settings` - `Keyboard Shortcuts`

In the `Navigation` section

- Click `Switch applications` and hit alt+tab
- Click `Switch windows of an app directly` and hit alt+`

Answer (score 0):

**Xubuntu 18.04 Lost Alt-F4 Log Out/Restart/Shut Down?**
*This applies to Xubuntu (xfce) only. It may apply to
more than 18.04.*
In a terminal execute xfce4-session-settings command to open
the 'Session and Startup' panel. In the general tab, Logout Settings
make sure that 'Prompt on logout' is TICKED. If this is not ticked
then the command xfce4-session-logout will execute immediately.
If it is ticked then a pop-up window will appear offering options
**Log Out  Restart  Shut Down   or  Cancel**.
If Alt-F4 does nothing, then create a keyboard short-cut for it:
Open the mouse menu, select Setting, Keyboard and then the
Applications Short Cuts tab.
Click +Add at the bottom right. In the Shortcut Command tab, in the
Command box enter
xfce4-session-logout
and click OK.
Then hold down the Alt key and tap the F4 key.
Close the panels.
Now type Alt-F4 and the Log Out/Restart/Shut Down option
panel should appear.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that in **Window Behavior** policy has been set to **Focus under mouse.**

I switched it to **Focus follows mouse** and Alt+Tab works alright now.

More on it can be read here: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=88727

[image]